# How to get array of all objects element?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the following complex array

```
var complex = [
   {
      name: '1',
      values: [1,2,3]
   },
   {
      name: '2',
      values: [4,5,6]
   }
]
```

I need to get the following result:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Is it possible to get by using undescorejs? So I don't want write own loops and ifs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
_.flatten(_.pluck(complex, 'values'))
```

or you can write this differently

```
_(complex).chain().pluck('values').flatten().value()
```